# Exception notifier - how to display own error pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I use **exception_notification** gem for handling an errors in an app.
My **ApplicationController** looks like this:

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception,
                :with => :render_error
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,
                :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError,
                :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController,
                :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction,
                :with => :render_not_found
  end

  def render_not_found(exception)
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier
      .exception_notification(request.env, exception)
      .deliver
    render :template => "/errors/404.html.erb",
      :layout => 'errors.html.erb'
    return     
  end

  def render_error(exception)
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier
      .exception_notification(request.env, exception)
      .deliver
    render :template => "/errors/500.html.erb",
           :layout => 'errors.html.erb'
    return
  end
```

In **/config/enviroments/productions.rg** in the end of the file I have:

```
config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
  :email_prefix => "[MY APP| Error Report] ",
  :sender_address => %{"MY APP" <err@my-app.com>},
  :exception_recipients => 'my_email@gmail.com'
end
```

when I get the error on the app - eg. `Article.find(not-existing-ID)`, I'll get the standard error page (ERROR 500) from `/public/500.html` and not from the file specified  in application controller... How is that possible? Past hours I tried to find the problem, but I still don't know the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me - from application_controller.rb:

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
end
```

and

```
  private
  def render_404(exception)
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(request.env, exception,
      :data => {:User => current_user.full_name, :Email => current_user.email, :UserID => current_user.id}).deliver
    @not_found_path = exception.message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'pages/404', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404}
    end
  end
  def render_500(exception)
    ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.exception_notification(request.env, exception,
      :data => {:User => current_user.full_name, :Email => current_user.email, :UserID => current_user.id}).deliver
    @error = exception
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'pages/500', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 500 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 500}
    end
  end
```

Note: I have my custom error pages in /app/views/pages. Called 500.html.haml and 404.html.haml

I also have this in my routes.rb (note a *hash* after 'pages rather than a forward-slash):

```
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    match '*not_found', to: 'pages#404'
  end
```

PS. See updated instructions here: http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2012/01/rails-3-1-adding-custom-404-and-500-error-pages

Answer (score 0):

Hi this works for me try it!

In the application_controller.rb you can add these codes:

```
 if Rails.env.production?
  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :render_404
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
  end
 end
```

This codes checks if you are running your rails app using production mode and catches different rescue errors.

In the same controller "application_controller.rb" add these codes:

```
def render_404(exception)
    @not_found_path = exception.message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def render_500(exception)
    logger.info exception.backtrace.join("\n")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/internal_server_error', layout:      'layouts/application', status: 500 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 500}
    end
  end
```

These methods will specify the page you want to display when your app catches an error,
then create a controller named: errors_controller.rb
then in your **app/view/errors**
create a file named:

- internal_server_error.html.erb 
  and
- not_found.html.erb

and in your **routes.rb**
add these codes:

```
 match '/internal_server_error', :to => 'errors#internal_server_error'
 match '/not_found', :to => 'errors#not_found'
```